# java jersey server side error (500) parameters are wrong?

Tags: java, json, xml, jersey

Hi there are the title says im having a couple of issues. my client keeps bring up an error 500 but not sure what it is in the server that is bring up the error. i think it might be the parameters passed but i am not sure. I have issues with the commented code in the client as well but I thought it was particular to the parameters but now I have hit an issue (with the un-commented code in the body of client) so now im not sure where to move on from here. I think it might be the paths but I think i just need a fresh pair of eye to point out what stupid mistake i made. Please let me what you think and answer below. thank you!

client

```
public class Tester {

private static URI getBaseURI(){
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/Assignment-tomcat_with_custom_api").build();
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());

    /*
    //example of creation
    Film film = new Film(50000000, "film1", 1155, "film1", "film1", "film1");
    ClientResponse response = service.path("rest").path("films").path(""+film.getId()).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(ClientResponse.class, film);
    if(response.getStatus() == 201){
        System.out.println("Film has been created");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Film had failed to be created. Response status:"+response.getStatus());
    }
    */

    System.out.println();
    //get all films
    System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("films").accept(
            MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class));

}


}
```

server

```
@Path("/films")
public class FilmListResource {

@Context UriInfo uriInfo;
@Context Request request;

//returns all films to browser
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public ArrayList<Film> getFilmListBrowser(){
    FilmDAO dao = new FilmDAO();
    return dao.getAllFilms();
}

//list of film applications
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public ArrayList<Film> getFilmList(){
    FilmDAO dao = new FilmDAO();
    return dao.getAllFilms();
}

//return number of films
@GET
@Path("count")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getCount(){
    FilmDAO dao = new FilmDAO();
    return String.valueOf(dao.getAllFilms().size());
}

@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void newFilm(@FormParam("title") String title,
                    @FormParam("director") String director,
                    @FormParam("year") int year,
                    @FormParam("stars") String stars,
                    @FormParam("review") String review,
                    @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse)
                    throws IOException{
    FilmDAO dao = new FilmDAO();
    ArrayList<Film> films = dao.getAllFilms();
    int id = films.get(films.size()-1).getId()+1;
    Film film = new Film(id, title, year, director, stars, review);
    dao.addFilm(film);

    servletResponse.sendRedirect(".../create_film.html");
}


/*
 * allows id to be used as a parameter to retrieve a film
*/  
@Path("{Film}")
public FilmResource getFilm (@PathParam("Film") String id){
    System.out.println("milestone 1");
    return new FilmResource(uriInfo, request, id);
}



}



public class FilmResource {
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context Request request;

    String id;

public FilmResource(UriInfo uriInfo, Request request, String id){
    this.uriInfo = uriInfo;
    this.request = request;
    this.id = id;

}

//application integration
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Film getFilm(){
    FilmDAO dao = new FilmDAO();
    int film_id = Integer.valueOf(id);
    Film film = dao.getFilmByID(film_id);
    if(film == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("Film could not be found using id:"+film_id);
    }
    return film;
}

//make browser pages
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public Film getFilmHtml(){
    FilmDAO dao = new FilmDAO();
    int film_id = Integer.valueOf(id);
    Film film = dao.getFilmByID(film_id);
    if(film == null){
        throw new RuntimeException("Film could not be found using id:"+film_id);
    }
    return film;
}

@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response putFilm(JAXBElement<Film> JaxFilm){
    Response res;
    Film film = JaxFilm.getValue();
    FilmDAO dao = new FilmDAO();

    if(dao.getFilmByID(film.getId()) != null){
        res = Response.noContent().build();
    }else{
        res = Response.created(uriInfo.getAbsolutePath()).build();
    }
    dao.addFilm(film);
    return res;
}
}
```

Comment: you should check server log

Comment: Multiple get method is there